# Removing all jsPlumb endpoints from a div

Tags: javascript, html, jsplumb

I am trying to remove all jsPlumb endpoints from a div with a source endpoint at right and a target at the left.

[image]

Here is the code that adds the endpoints to the div:

`addEndpointsToDiv("exp1", ["Right"], ["Left"])`

```
function addEndpointsToDiv(divId, sourceAnchors, targetAnchors) {
for (var i = 0; i < sourceAnchors.length; i++) 
{
 var sourceUUID = divId + sourceAnchors[i];
 instance.addEndpoint(divId, sourceEndpoint, 
  {
    anchor: sourceAnchors[i], uuid: sourceUUID
  });
}
for (var j = 0; j < targetAnchors.length; j++) 
 {
 var targetUUID = divId + targetAnchors[j];
 instance.addEndpoint(divId, targetEndpoint, { anchor: targetAnchors[j], uuid: targetUUID });
 }
};
```

Question: How do I remove all of these end points from only one div?

Here are a few of my failed attempts:

Attempt #1:

```
instance.deleteEndpoint(divId)
```

Attempt #2

```
var endpoint = instance.getEndpoint(divId)
while (endpoint != null)
{
  instance.deleteEndpoint(divId)
  endpoint = instance.getEndpoint(divId)
}
```

Attempt #3

```
var endPoints = instance.selectEndpoints(divId)
endPoints.each(function (endpoint) {
instance.deleteEndpoint(endPoint)
});
```

Attempt #4

```
var endpoints = instance.getendpoints(divid)
for (endpoint in endpoints)
   instance.deleteendpoint(endpoint.endpoint)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsplumb/Hsf6oKQiBt4

I only needed this one line of code:

```
instance.removeAllEndpoints(divId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one without needing the instance :

```
jsPlumb.removeAllEndpoints("divId");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet:

```
jsPlumb.removeAllEndpoints("divId")
```

what's actually happening is that you're calling that method on the "default" instance of jsPlumb, whose existence is a hangover from jsPlumb's early days. Calling `removeAllEndpoints` on the "default" instance of jsPlumb will have no effect on any other instances you have created.

In 4.x this "default" instance of jsPlumb is no longer present.